# Where in System Preferences do I find how to enable system extensions?

Tags: macos, system-settings

A friend of mine has a Mid 2012 MacBook Air running Catalina, and he's trying to get the Android emulator BlueStacks running on it.  He gets an error saying

> System extension blocked.
> Enable the extension from Security & Privacy System Preferences pane by clicking 'Allow' button and BlueStacks will launch again.

I looked in that pane, and couldn't find anything like that.  I'm obviously missing something here but I don't know what!

A screenshot of the error is attached:

[image: Screenshot of error message.]

Comment: It tells you right in the error message what to do and has a button to open it!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open System Preferences [image]
2. Open the Security & Privacy preference pane [image]
3. Choose the General tab [image]
4. Click the lock to make changes. [image] <sub>(In versions of macOS as applicable.)</sub>
5. Click Allow in the bottom-right.
   This Allow button will only show if there is a system extension that is pending approval.